# PHP ampq + rabbit MQ -- long running producer: can send messages to queues already declared, but can't declare new queues

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I have a "producer" that's supposed to be always running, but it seems that after a day or so, it is still able to send messages to queues it has previously declared, but when trying to declare a new queue, it blows up with:

```
'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPHeartbeatMissedException' with message 'Missed server heartbeat' in /php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/AbstractIO.php:140
```

I thought that the heartbeat was only for consumers (since there's no place to check for heartbeats on producers)? Is it a bug that the heartbeat is being checked when I'm not a "consumer"?

Or is it that my script also becomes a "consumer" when I declare a queue, because it needs to "consume" feedback from the server that the queue is ready for use or something?

The way it's currently set up, what work-around could I use periodically to check if `queue_declare` would blow up if it was run, so that when I do need to run `queue_declare` it doesn't blow up unexpectedly?

I'm using `AMQPSSLConnection` on the most recent version (2.9.2), and `$connection->isConnected()` is returning `true` the whole time. Heartbeat is set to 15 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the next minor release of `php-amqplib` will have a method added: `$connection->checkHeartBeat();` (it was committed to the project repo just days before I posted this question). Calling this regularly would solve the problem.

In the meantime, calling `$connection->wait(null, true);` regularly is also a working solution.